# pass command line arguments in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I am trying to retrieve a line from a text file, write it to a file locally, and then combine it with the list of IPs into a new file.  I am having issues escaping all of the parameters I think though, because it's only doing the first line of the list of hosts.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

file="~/hosts"

while IFS= read -r server; do
ssh -t name@$server  "sudo awk -F '=' 'FNR == 2 {print \$2}' /etc/version.txt > ~/version"
done < "$file"
paste ~/hosts ~/version > ~/ip_and_version
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `~` won't get expanded within quotes. You can use `file=~/"hosts"` or  `file="$HOME/hosts"`
2. `ssh` will slurp up stdin: this is your main problem. Do `ssh -t ... < /dev/null`
3. be aware that you're writing to the version file *on the remote server*, not into your own home directory on your local machine. Did you want this instead?

   ```
   ssh -t "name@$server" "sudo awk -F= 'FNR == 2 {print \$2}' /etc/version.txt" < /dev/null > ~/version
   ```

---

How about:

```
remote_command="sudo awk -F '=' 'FNR == 2 {print \$2}' /etc/version.txt"

readarray -t servers < ~/hosts
for server in "${servers[@]}"; do
    ssh -t name@$server "$remote_command"
done > ~/version

paste ~/hosts ~/version > ~/ip_and_version
```

Comment: I'm putting my unfinished answer on hold and hoping to improve yours. (1) In my Kubuntu `ssh -t … </dev/null` says `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.` This works: `</dev/tty`. (2) Redirecting to `~/version` seems to redirect password prompts from `sudo` as well. (3) `>` will overwrite `~/version` over and over, so it's not a good way in a loop. (4) And even with `>>` a remote error may render `~/hosts` and `~/version` out of sync. How about capturing the output from `ssh` to a variable and building `~/ip_and_version` from `$server` and the variable?

Comment: This example asks for password without echoing it and captures the output of the remote command: `stty -echo; foo="$(ssh who@where "sudo -S date")"; stty echo; echo`

Comment: I would have thought sudo prompts would be sent to stderr. Anyway, I added another version that avoids the stdin problem.

Comment: I make it community wiki, so feel free to edit.

Comment: `I would have thought sudo prompts would be sent to stderr`. True, but `ssh -t` allocates pseudo-terminal *on the remote side*. `sudo` does prompt to stderr but then stdout and stderr are "printed" by this pseudo-terminal (like they are normally printed to the console) and at this point you can no longer tell them apart; the *merged* stream is captured and transferred to the local side where it goes to stdout. Without `-t` the remote stdout and stderr are transferred separately, go to stdout and stderr on the local side and these are eventually merged (or not, if redirected) into what you see.

Comment: (cont'd) You can see the difference with `ssh anywhere 'ls -l /proc/self/fd'`, run it without and with `-t`.

Comment: Thank you!  I wasn't actually using the ~ in my script, just through that in there instead of my actual pathing!  The /dev/null piece worked!  Also I have to do >> ./version as it was just giving me a blank version file, but i could see data getting written to it if I tailed it while the program was happening!

Comment: There are a few things I should account for as well, like if it can't reach a host, or if there is no file, etc but I have it working now at least.  I also added -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no to keep it from failing.

Comment: Instead of messing around with the paste command which is not ever going to be accurate unless you are 100% sure your IP list is correct and the file is on every server, I have come up with this:

while IFS= read -r server; do
ssh -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@$server  "echo $SSH_CONNECTION && command 1 && command2 < /dev/null >> ./file
done < "$file"

Comment: SSH_CONNECTION is not going to give me the correct IP for my needs, as I'm connecting to a NATed IP, and it shows the local IP of the server instead.  
What I came up with is to echo Server Unreachable if the command exits without code 0.
Here is my completed script if anyone is doing something similar - getting hardware info and uptime for a long list of servers:  https://pastebin.com/FR06MqrP